# XSS protection on already production project

Tags: jsp, servlets, xss

We are having a servlet and struts based application. Its a huge application with queries written in jsp and prone to XSS (request values printed as-is in jsp). Its a huge application with 200 jsp.

We want to fix XSS attack in such a way that minimum code changes are done so that QA dev cycle is small and QA get more time.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The only approach that really works is to create a UI layer.  That is, use a framework like Vaadin, Google Web Toolkit, or similar, which abstracts away all HTML, JavaScript, etc, so that the developer working on the UI look and feel, or creating a new page, or modifying a page, doesn't have to consider the security implications of his/her changes.

This is particularly important as most developers don't know the security implications of their changes, so abstracting them away will help protect against lack of knowledge/experience.  It also protects against simple errors that the developer makes - after all, we know that code always has bugs.

It's also very beneficial in other ways.  Using a UI framework instead of scattering UI code everywhere makes maintenance easier.  It makes the UI look and feel consistent.  It makes changes to the look and feel occur throughout the UI instead of spot fixed everywhere.  A bug - or a vuln - that exists because the original implementation wasn't perfect can be fixed in one place, instead of spot fixed everywhere.

In the interim, until you create a UI layer in your application, you should look at OWASP's ESAPI.  THey offer bolt-on XSS protection.  It does a decent job, though it is very likely that it will break either some functionality in your UI or will not protect some functionality in your UI.  This is because it is not fully integrated with your application - it's bolt on - so it is unlikely to be perfect.